# Git URIs does not match SSH URI specification

Tags: git, github, ssh, port, uri

I'm studying the [SSH URI specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04#section-3.3) in order to understand a bit more the URLs used to access repositories in services like Github or Bitbucket via SSH.

A typical SSH Github URL looks like this: `git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git`, which I think can be decomposed in the following sections:

```
   scheme           authority
     |                 |
    /‾‾\/‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾\
    ssh://git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git
          \_/ \________/ \_______________/
           |      |              |
          user   host           port
```

What I don't understand is the port section. The [official general URI specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.3) states that ports should contain only numeric values. The [SSH URI scheme specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04#section-3.3) sticks to the general URI specification. And the [OpenSSH config manual](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#Port) does the same.

Why then do they use path-like text in the port section? Is this a deviation from the standard that has been established de facto? Or am I understanding wrong this whole thing?

I'd appreciate if anyone can clarify this.

Comment: The normal Git syntax is either `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` (note that there are no colons after `ssh:` here), **or** `git@github.com:user/repo.git` (note that there is no `ssh:` here). You are not supposed to combine the two. When using the second form, you're not using a standard URL/URI at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL:DR** The syntax described in the question is a heritage from an old program called `rcp`, and does not conform to the URI spec.

**Explanation**

Thanks to @jthill and @torek for pointing me to the right direction. This is my guess after some days of research.

All three of the remote operation programs in OpenSSH (`ssh`, `scp`, `sftp`), accept arguments that comply to the SSH URI scheme, described in its own [IETF specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04).

Broadly speaking, any URI is composed of five components: scheme, authority, path, query, and fragment. Furthermore, the authority can be composed by userinfo, host, and port. In the case of the SSH URI scheme, only scheme, authority and path are allowed.

```
   scheme     authority           path
     |           |                 |
    /‾‾\/‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾\/‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾\
    ssh://git@github.com:22/myuser/myrepo.git
          \_/\_________/\_/
           |      |      |
          user   host   port
```

However, there's an alternative syntax that's quite similar to the stardard SSH URI scheme, but not exactly compliant with it. This syntax is a heritage from the old `rcp` (remote copy) program created in 1981, almost a decade and a half before the creation of the URI protocol. When the [Berkeley r-commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_r-commands) were released, to specify the destination of an operation in `rsh` (remote shell) or `rlogin` (remote login) it was only required to specify the remote machine in which the operation was going to be performed, and probably the user in that machine as well. At that time, the consensus was the syntax `username@hostname`. The `rcp` program, however, had an additional condition, given that in order to copy files from, or to, one remote location, the developer was required to specify the path of the file in that remote machine, in addition to the user and host, just as the `cp` program does. The syntax they come across was to append the path to the end of the user/host declaration, separated by a colon: `username@hostname:path/to/file` (as described in its own [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rcp)).

```
    git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git
    \_/ \________/ \_______________/
     |      |              |
    user   host           path
```

When the OpenSSH team implemented the `scp` program, they wanted to provide a familiar API to the developers already using `rcp`, so they decided to keep support for this old, custom syntax, in addition to the new standarized SSH URI scheme. Then, in 2005 Git entered the scene with native support for SSH, probably using OpenSSH under the hood, and the *rcp-like syntax* ended up being used when SSH is used for remote operations like `clone`, `fetch`, `push`, and `pull`. The Git documentation calls this syntax *scp-like syntax*, and it is briely described in the [scp manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/scp.1), the [git-clone docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls), and the [Git protocols docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_ssh_protocol). In the end, despite its lack of standarization, it seems to be the syntax used by all cloud Git services like Github or Bitbucket, when offering a URL for cloning repos.

Comment: Why can't they use the `ssh:` or `git:` scheme properly? The documentation seems to be happy to call it a URL, but the `@` isn't legal in a scheme. Each vendor is basically declaring their own`git@me.TLD:` scheme. Eventually some git dev will add their own service-specific decorations, and then you will have URL's with invalid schemes that also don't interoperate.

Comment: thank you for both this question and answer, did you happen to find out, and if so, would it be possible to edit to include this for reference sake: when an IDE like Eclipse with eGit sets up a source remote repository using this form user@domain:/repopath.git - and you give it that URI, so the repo path field looks like it has this .git extension ... what you're saying is that it is not going to incorrectly look for the location /repopath.git/ because it knows this last .git isn't part of the path, but is part of the URI protocol/format, even though it is not part of the standard?

Answer (score 0):

Git repos can be referred to using more than just URIs. You can use paths, for instance, and you can use most (maybe all, haven't checked) things the `ssh` *command* would take. The ssh command doesn't require an ssh URI either: it already knows it's the one to interpret the resource identifier, so the restrictions imposed on *uniform* resource identifiers don't have any value to add here, there's nothing to be gained by following them.

The complete syntax Git accepts for a repository identifier can be found in the `git clone` docs, under [`GIT URLS`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jthill. So looking at the Git Urls link, is it safe to say that the usual URL that Github provides to clone a repo is in a scp-like syntax, which can be used with SSH, and that's why it differs from the standard SSH URI?